# Naming excel sheets using list C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to create 12 new worksheets in an excel workbook. I would then like to change the name of each sheet to be the name of a month (January - December).

Code:

```
List<string> Months = new List<string> { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
for (int i = 0; i < Months.Count; i++)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet "sheet" + i = (Worksheet)xlApp.Worksheets["Sheet" + (i+1)];
                "sheet" + i.Name = Months[i];
            }
```

As for the variable names of the sheets, I would like to name each worksheet `"sheet" + i (a number 0-11)`.

A full example would look like this...

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet0 = (Worksheet)xlApp.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
            sheet0.Name = "Jan";
```

Everything works fine besides the variable naming `("sheet" + i)`. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have `"sheet" + i.Name` which is attempting to reference the variable `i` as if it has the property `Name` as opposed to what (I think) you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @gravity Oh ok. That is not what I am trying to do. I want to name the worksheet `"sheet" + i`. Then I want to change the name of that sheet... Do you know how I could do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you have:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet "sheet" + i = (.....)
"sheet" + i.Name = Months[i];
```

In the example they indeed used a variable called `sheet0`, but you don't need to follow it so strictly. A variable can have any name like `mySheet` or `nextSheet`.

You don't need to try "build" a numbered variable name like `"sheet"+i`. Even more, that will simply **not work**. Please note that `sheet0` is a complete variable name. The `0` is part of the name, there are no `"` (quotes) and no "adding" a number to the variable name. You cannot "create" new variables in such way.

Instead, just pick any normal name:

```
for(....)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet justOneOfTheSheetsAtTime = (.....)
    justOneOfTheSheetsAtTime.Name = Months[i];
}
```

It doesn't matter that it is inside a loop. Each time the loop iterates, the same variable name wil be used and a different sheet will be put into it. There is no problem with using a single variable to inspect&change a hundred of sheets through a loop.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not realize I could reuse the same name.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that this worked for me successfully, after a quick validation against what you wanted from the comments:

```
List<string> Months = new List<string> { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };

Application xlApp = new Application();
Workbook bkMonths = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
xlApp.Visible = true;

for (int i = 0; i < Months.Count; i++)
{
    Worksheet sheetCurrent = xlApp.Worksheets.Add();
    sheetCurrent.Name = Months[i];
}
```